# Awesome WM remove round corners for maximized windows

Tags: lua, lua-table, awesome-wm

Why does this code fail?

```
client.connect_signal("manage", function (c)
    if not c.maximized then
        c.shape = gears.shape.rounded_rect
    end
end)

client.connect_signal("property::maximized", function (c)
    c.shape = gears.shape.rectangle
end)
```

It also fails when setting rounded corners in a callback for `rule = { }`

Comment: What does "fail" mean? Do you have an error message? Do the windows always have rounded rects? Never? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: Also, `property::maximized` is emitted when `c.maximized` *changes*, not when it becomes `true`. Thus, you should also check `if c.maximized` in there, I think.